# Linux system() API

Tags: c, linux

Can anybody tell me the output of the below code, whether "bye" will be printed or not?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

 system("ls -l");
 printf("bye");

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's rude to yell...  please don't write in all capitals.

Comment: Wouldn't be easier if you just compiled and ran the code?

Comment: I have edited this to remove the SHOUTING.... we're not mind-readers and doing the dirty work for you... try it out and see for yourself.... am voting to close this question as it's useless....

Comment: I downvoted because the user never indicated if they attempted to compile the code themselves.

Answer (score 8):

`man system` says:

> ```
>   int system(const char *command);
> ```
>
> `system()` executes a command specified in `command` by calling `/bin/sh -c command`, and returns after the command has been completed.

And after `system()` returned, your `printf` will be executed.

Comment: Ok I was not that yelling by writing in caps.
Just since new to stack overflow,I wrote it in caps so that it should go to the proper queue..

Also, Mr.tommieb75,we are here to exchange our answers not insulting each other just because one of us knows the answer.
How rudely u have wrote ,If you cant provide me the answers ,then its better to keep quite or suggest me in a polite way.

I belive you are matured enough to have this sense.

Its a forum, to help others not like forced to help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will be printed.

Why don't you compile it and test it for yourself?  Cut and paste what you've written to a file, e.g. foo.c, and then do the following

```
gcc -o foo foo.c
./foo
```

As there is no newline character after your printf("bye") it will end up at the start of your current line; putting printf("bye\n") instead will be a little more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it? There's no conditional statement, so every part of the code will be executed.

It will print the output of the command provided by system and then print "bye"

Answer (score 0):

The program is going to execute `ls -l` just fine.

Also, "bye" should indeed be printed.  However, since you have not included a '\n' character you will only be seeing it with your prompt appended to it.

Also, if you are not seeing it, then for some reason your output is not flushing when the program exits.  Adding a '\n' character may very well fix that issue if that is what you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends upon the free memory.
You will need to check return value of the system command.it returns 0 on success.
Your printf statement will be called but not sure that system command will always success.

Thanks,
Neel